# UX Presentation

Tags: design, presentation

The CEO has asked me to give him a small UX presentation on my thought process and what is that I'm planning to change with respect to the old application.
For your information, the old existing application is used by a lot of clients and right now there is no scope to strip or tweak any existing functionality.
I was thinking of focusing on the positioning of certain elements in terms of buttons, forms, popups etc.

Can anyone suggest me any ideas on how to?

Thanks so much,
Rolz

Answer (score 1):

We can usually have expert review on existing system based on usability principles. Also you can run user testing on existing system and user surveys if possible.

Your presentation can have these things
1) You can give overview of ux and its importance.(case study of design failures/redesign)
2) ur findng from expert review.
3) Categorize your finding in expert review quick fixes, should have, good to have.
4) uset testing video/survey results (optional)
5) redesign few screens with quick win fixes.

Comment: Thank Suresh for your sharing your ideas. Will use some of your inputs.

Comment: Great !! Atleast it helps you in some way!!